# ExcelDataReader FilterColumn usage

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I am trying to return a data set that returns the first row as the header row(this is working) as well as filter out entire columns from the data depending on their column header.

`ExcelDataReader 3.4.0` introduced the `FilterColumn` callback option which I am attempting to utilize.

Below is my `AsDataSet` call

```
           var ds = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
            {

                // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use a row from the 
                // data as column names.
                UseHeaderRow = true,

                // Gets or sets a callback to determine which row is the header row. 
                // Only called when UseHeaderRow = true.
                ReadHeaderRow = (rowReader) => {
                    // F.ex skip the first row and use the 2nd row as column headers:
                    rowReader.ToString();
                },

                FilterColumn = (rowReader, columnIndex) => { 
                    return //if header == "string" filter out entire column
                }
            }
        });
```

Above when I try to look at the row,index pair of the column and test to see if it contains the phrase it returns it anyway. What is the proper usage of `FilterColumn` in this scenario?

Link to github : https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/tree/v3.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the headers in a list in `ReadHeaderRow`, and check the index in `FilterColumn`:

```
    var headers = new List<string>();

    ds = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true,

            ReadHeaderRow = rowReader => {
                for (var i = 0; i < rowReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    headers.Add(Convert.ToString(rowReader.GetValue(i)));
            },

            FilterColumn = (columnReader, columnIndex) =>
                headers.IndexOf("string") != columnIndex
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ended up changing slightly to do this:  FilterColumn = (columnReader, columnIndex) => 
                    !headers[columnIndex].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SKIP")

Answer (score 3):

It is really easy! Just use it in this way:

```
FilterColumn = (rowReader, colIndex) => 
    rowReader[colIndex].ToString() != "string"
```

or

```
FilterColumn = (rowReader, colIndex) => 
    !rowReader[colIndex].ToString().Contains("string")
```