# Ignore specific columns from loading into the DataSet using ExcelDataReader?

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I'm using [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to load the data into an `DataSet`, which will be eventually be loaded into an `DataGrid` in WPF. I have specific columns with headers as `SLNO` and `FY` which I don't want to include. How can I ignore those columns using `FilterColumn` mentioned [here](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/releases/tag/v3.4.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = e.PropertyName == "SLNO" || e.PropertyName == "FY";
}
```

Comment: I know it works. But my question was different. Thought why to even add them in the first place i.e. into the `DataSet`. Maybe loading performance can be improved a tiny bit lol.

Comment: Seems like you can only use the FilterColumn property to filter out columns based on their index: https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/blob/e6000f5578c500d4e3818ae3d2b464bf40305372/test/ExcelDataReader.Tests/ExcelBinaryReaderTest.cs

Comment: It's okay. The current solution is working fine. Though can you post sample code?

Comment: Filtering out columns using `FilterColumn` based on their index. I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908729/exceldatareader-filtercolumn-usage) but didn't quite understand that.

Comment: See the link in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter these columns at the time of the display, use the following code :

```
    gridview.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

Or :

```
   DataView view = new DataView(DataSet.table[0]);
   DataTable table2 = view.ToTable(false, "FirstColumn", "SecondColumn",      "ThirdColumn");

   GridDataView.DataSource = Table2;
```

Comment: The first line of code you posted is not for WPF it seems. Anyways, I used `DataTable.Columns.Remove["ColumnName"]` for now. Actually I don't even want those columns in my current application, they are for some other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `FilterColumn` works

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    List<string> skipColumns = new List<string> { "SLNO", "FY" };
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
            {
                UseHeaderRow = true,
                FilterColumn = (rowReader, columnIndex) =>
                {
                    return !skipColumns.Contains((rowReader[columnIndex].ToString()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```